# Java CommonsLang StringUtils.isBlank on instant

Tags: java, null, boolean, java.time.instant

I know it's a silly question but here's my issue.

I'm working on an object and needed to check all the member variables for nullity, empty chars etc... but in my object I don't only have strings, I also have Instant and Booleans.

I've tried with some other methods from StringUtils and read the documentation but didn't find out any way to do so.

Any tip ?
I know i can make the check without stringUtils but I can't believe they didn't figured a way out.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So you wonder why a class named ___String___ Utils doesn't include stuff to check `boolean` and `Instant`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Objects` class from `java.util` package to perform null checks in different type of objects, e.g.:

```
Date d = null;
Character c = new Character('c');
System.out.println(Objects.isNull(d));
System.out.println(Objects.isNull(c));
```

You can also use methods like `requireNonNull` to validate the values before sending to a `method` or a service.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)'s javadoc for `Objects` class.

Comment: Thank you Darshan!

Comment: It's no better than `if (obj == null)`. Its only usefulness is as a method reference predicate.